# Media query not workng on Bootstrap breakpoint

Tags: bootstrap-4, media-queries

I am using Bootstrap 4 and trying to use the following code:

**EDITED**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) { 
    .marbling {
        background: none;
        border-left: 0 solid;
        }
    h2.podstrona-tytul {
        margin-top: 180px;  
        text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

But I can see effect not at 575px but 574px. If <576px wasn't Bootstrap breakpoint, there were be no big problem, but as it is, on 575px website looks really messy. If I set `max-width: 576px` changes are visible form 576px which is bad as well.. What could be the way to fix it?

Comment: Can setup a snippet with your code that shows it not working at 575 but working at 574? Your col-sm-1.jasne-tlo style is switching the display style for me at 575 versus 576 on a test page I created.

Comment: This is a small part of big wordpress page and I am not sure, how to reduce it to snippet. But you are right, `.col-sm-1` part is working (I will deleted it from the question not to make confusion), but the rest is not.

Answer (score 0):

It’s difficult to understand what’s happening without seeing the code that’s giving you problems, but one thing you might want to consider is, rather than using `max-width: 575px`, which is the opposite of how Bootstrap works, try setting your styles using `min-width:576px`, something like this:

```css
.marbling {
    background: none;
    border: 0.25rem solid red;
    border-left: 0;
}

.podstrona-tytul {
    margin-top: 180px;  
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:576px) {
    .marbling {
        background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/dWxZXGI.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
        border-left: 0.25rem solid red;
    }

    .podstrona-tytul {
        margin-top: 16px;
        text-align: left;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-6 marbling">
            <h2 class="podstrona-tytul">Media query not workng on Bootstrap breakpoint</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Coded this way, at 575px wide or less, the h2 tag has a 180px top margin and the text is centered, there's no background image, and there's no left border. At 576px wide or more, the h2 tag has a 16px top margin and the text is aligned left, and there is a background image with a left border.